# After delete Member the Relation is not deleted

Tags: jpa

I have a problem with orphanRemoval. When I Delete Member and if there is no others Members referenced relation given, this relation should be deleted.  But this is not the case. There is the moyen to do this with JPA configs, or I should write logic in Service ?

```
public class Member {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public RelationEntity getBornRelation() {
        return bornRelation;
    }
}

public class Relation {
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bornrelation")
    public List<MemberEntity> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you've defined two separate associations between `Member` and `Relation`. I suspect that wasn't intentional. If you want to keep the association bidirectional, you need to make the 'one' side the owning side of the association by adding `mappedBy="bornRelation"` to the `@OneToMany`. Otherwise, changes to `Member.bornRelation` will not be reflected in `Relation.children` and vice versa.

Secondly, do **not** use `CascadeType.ALL` with `@ManyToOne`. `CascadeType.ALL` implies `CascadeType.REMOVE` and an attempt to remove the 'one' side of the association will fail as long as the 'many' side still contains other child entities that refer to the parent entity. JPA will not check if the deletion is possible. It will simply issue a `DELETE` to the database, resulting in constraint violations.

(you can keep using `CascadeType.ALL` with `@OneToMany`, but remember that you still need to make sure `Member.bornRelation` is set properly when adding new elements to `Relation.children`. JPA will not take care of that for you)

I believe the above already answers your question. What you want cannot be done by JPA configuration only, you need additional logic to check whether the `Relation` to delete is the last child of its parent entity. This, by the way, has nothing to do with orphan removal. Orphan removal is about removing child entities (and not parent entities).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I was trying in different way...  If I use mappedBy in  OneToMany, when I add a child to this relation, this is not update che Member side. So.. i was decided to   add annotation JoinColumn at OneToMany side. And it works quasi like I expect.

Comment: As I said, once you add `mappedBy`, `Member.bornRelation` becomes the *owning* side of the association. That means you can only establish/update the association by setting `Member.bornRelation` to an appropriate value. Changes to `Relation.children` will be ignored, because that side is not the owning side. At the same time, the 'many' side cannot be the owning side of a bidirectional one-to-many association. To make it the owning side, you'd need to make the association unidirectional by removing `Member.bornRelation` altogether.